# Why the CNN arrived at highest accuracy only after 100 iterations and cannot get improved?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

First of all, truly thanks for your watching. This output confuse me in several days. Whyyyy the CNN arrived at 90% accuracy after 100 iterations and cannot improve any more? Though I reduce or increase layers of CNN would not affect the output. Though I reduce the learning rate to 1e-4 that would not affect the output. This let me feel crazy.

```
I0520 17:18:54.184824  8010 solver.cpp:280] Learning Rate Policy: step
I0520 17:18:54.185271  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:18:56.232154  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.104375
I0520 17:18:56.232197  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.693147 (* 1 = 0.693147 loss)
I0520 17:18:56.466557  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 0, loss = 0.693147
I0520 17:18:56.466586  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.693147 (* 1 = 0.693147 loss)
I0520 17:18:56.466620  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 0, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:19:11.837409  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 100, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:19:13.835307  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.9025
I0520 17:19:13.835340  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.322544 (* 1 = 0.322544 loss)
I0520 17:19:13.893486  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 100, loss = 0.130141
I0520 17:19:13.893525  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.130141 (* 1 = 0.130141 loss)
I0520 17:19:13.983126  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 100, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:19:30.863654  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 200, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:19:32.862107  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89375
I0520 17:19:32.862146  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.338875 (* 1 = 0.338875 loss)
I0520 17:19:32.920205  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 200, loss = 0.3774
I0520 17:19:32.920241  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.3774 (* 1 = 0.3774 loss)
I0520 17:19:33.014003  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 200, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:19:48.727584  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 300, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:19:50.727105  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.885625
I0520 17:19:50.727149  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.35577 (* 1 = 0.35577 loss)
I0520 17:19:50.784287  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 300, loss = 0.378196
I0520 17:19:50.784317  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.378196 (* 1 = 0.378196 loss)
I0520 17:19:50.864651  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 300, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:20:05.957052  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 400, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:20:07.961210  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89625
I0520 17:20:07.961241  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.333487 (* 1 = 0.333487 loss)
I0520 17:20:08.018559  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 400, loss = 0.247491
I0520 17:20:08.018585  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.247491 (* 1 = 0.247491 loss)
I0520 17:20:08.097172  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 400, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:20:23.099375  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 500, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:20:25.104033  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.87875
I0520 17:20:25.104063  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.369838 (* 1 = 0.369838 loss)
I0520 17:20:25.161242  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 500, loss = 0.377606
I0520 17:20:25.161267  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377606 (* 1 = 0.377606 loss)
I0520 17:20:25.240455  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 500, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:20:40.367671  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 600, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:20:42.372931  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.899375
I0520 17:20:42.372972  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.3275 (* 1 = 0.3275 loss)
I0520 17:20:42.431170  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 600, loss = 0.504837
I0520 17:20:42.431207  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.504837 (* 1 = 0.504837 loss)
I0520 17:20:42.509552  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 600, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:20:57.602491  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 700, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:20:59.610484  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8775
I0520 17:20:59.610515  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.37246 (* 1 = 0.37246 loss)
I0520 17:20:59.667711  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 700, loss = 0.377645
I0520 17:20:59.667740  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377646 (* 1 = 0.377646 loss)
I0520 17:20:59.746636  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 700, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:21:14.917335  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 800, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:21:16.927249  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89125
I0520 17:21:16.927291  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.344211 (* 1 = 0.344211 loss)
I0520 17:21:16.984709  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 800, loss = 0.630042
I0520 17:21:16.984740  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.630042 (* 1 = 0.630042 loss)
I0520 17:21:17.068943  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 800, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:21:32.367197  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 900, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:21:34.375227  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.88625
I0520 17:21:34.375259  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.354399 (* 1 = 0.354399 loss)
I0520 17:21:34.432396  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 900, loss = 0.251611
I0520 17:21:34.432428  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.251612 (* 1 = 0.251612 loss)
I0520 17:21:34.512991  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 900, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:21:49.736721  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1000, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:21:51.748107  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89625
I0520 17:21:51.748139  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.33392 (* 1 = 0.33392 loss)
I0520 17:21:51.805516  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1000, loss = 0.377219
I0520 17:21:51.805547  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.37722 (* 1 = 0.37722 loss)
I0520 17:21:51.891490  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1000, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:22:07.312000  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1100, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:22:09.324790  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8825
I0520 17:22:09.324831  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.362015 (* 1 = 0.362015 loss)
I0520 17:22:09.382184  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1100, loss = 0.377469
I0520 17:22:09.382210  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.37747 (* 1 = 0.37747 loss)
I0520 17:22:09.470769  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1100, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:22:24.663307  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1200, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:22:26.671860  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89375
I0520 17:22:26.671903  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.33863 (* 1 = 0.33863 loss)
I0520 17:22:26.729918  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1200, loss = 0.246504
I0520 17:22:26.729953  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.246505 (* 1 = 0.246505 loss)
I0520 17:22:26.816223  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1200, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:22:42.258044  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1300, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:22:44.267346  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.88875
I0520 17:22:44.267387  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.349121 (* 1 = 0.349121 loss)
I0520 17:22:44.324551  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1300, loss = 0.507589
I0520 17:22:44.324579  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.50759 (* 1 = 0.50759 loss)
I0520 17:22:44.406440  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1300, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:22:59.415982  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1400, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:23:01.426676  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89625
I0520 17:23:01.426718  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.334152 (* 1 = 0.334152 loss)
I0520 17:23:01.483747  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1400, loss = 0.250863
I0520 17:23:01.483773  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.250864 (* 1 = 0.250864 loss)
I0520 17:23:01.566565  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1400, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:23:16.813146  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1500, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:23:18.822875  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89875
I0520 17:23:18.822907  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.328215 (* 1 = 0.328215 loss)
I0520 17:23:18.879963  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1500, loss = 0.116459
I0520 17:23:18.879992  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.116459 (* 1 = 0.116459 loss)
I0520 17:23:18.971333  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1500, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:23:34.049043  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1600, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:23:36.062679  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.896875
I0520 17:23:36.062708  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.332045 (* 1 = 0.332045 loss)
I0520 17:23:36.119786  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1600, loss = 0.509788
I0520 17:23:36.119813  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.509789 (* 1 = 0.509789 loss)
I0520 17:23:36.203153  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1600, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:23:51.507007  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1700, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:23:53.517299  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8925
I0520 17:23:53.517330  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.341289 (* 1 = 0.341289 loss)
I0520 17:23:53.574323  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1700, loss = 0.247204
I0520 17:23:53.574349  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.247205 (* 1 = 0.247205 loss)
I0520 17:23:53.660018  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1700, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:24:08.737020  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1800, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:24:10.748651  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.90375
I0520 17:24:10.748685  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.318335 (* 1 = 0.318335 loss)
I0520 17:24:10.805716  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1800, loss = 0.12061
I0520 17:24:10.805747  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.120611 (* 1 = 0.120611 loss)
I0520 17:24:10.890601  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1800, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:24:25.873175  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 1900, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:24:27.883744  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89125
I0520 17:24:27.883777  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.34394 (* 1 = 0.34394 loss)
I0520 17:24:27.940755  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 1900, loss = 0.248079
I0520 17:24:27.940788  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.24808 (* 1 = 0.24808 loss)
I0520 17:24:28.023818  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 1900, lr = 0.01
I0520 17:24:43.362032  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2000, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:24:45.372015  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.890625
I0520 17:24:45.372057  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.345227 (* 1 = 0.345227 loss)
I0520 17:24:45.429081  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2000, loss = 0.24597
I0520 17:24:45.429111  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.245971 (* 1 = 0.245971 loss)
I0520 17:24:45.512468  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2000, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:25:00.576135  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2100, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:25:02.587014  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89375
I0520 17:25:02.587056  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.338609 (* 1 = 0.338609 loss)
I0520 17:25:02.644042  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2100, loss = 0.378319
I0520 17:25:02.644069  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.37832 (* 1 = 0.37832 loss)
I0520 17:25:02.727481  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2100, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:25:17.801662  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2200, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:25:19.811810  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.88875
I0520 17:25:19.811852  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.349157 (* 1 = 0.349157 loss)
I0520 17:25:19.868859  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2200, loss = 0.509671
I0520 17:25:19.868885  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.509672 (* 1 = 0.509672 loss)
I0520 17:25:19.953173  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2200, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:25:35.135272  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2300, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:25:37.147276  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.890625
I0520 17:25:37.147317  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.345208 (* 1 = 0.345208 loss)
I0520 17:25:37.204273  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2300, loss = 0.37789
I0520 17:25:37.204303  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377891 (* 1 = 0.377891 loss)
I0520 17:25:37.287936  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2300, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:25:52.305204  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2400, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:25:54.314997  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8775
I0520 17:25:54.315038  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.372589 (* 1 = 0.372589 loss)
I0520 17:25:54.372031  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2400, loss = 0.377802
I0520 17:25:54.372058  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377803 (* 1 = 0.377803 loss)
I0520 17:25:54.456874  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2400, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:26:09.711889  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2500, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:26:11.721444  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8875
I0520 17:26:11.721487  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.35174 (* 1 = 0.35174 loss)
I0520 17:26:11.779080  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2500, loss = 0.247256
I0520 17:26:11.779130  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.247256 (* 1 = 0.247256 loss)
I0520 17:26:11.871363  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2500, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:26:26.890584  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2600, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:26:28.901217  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.888125
I0520 17:26:28.901259  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.350424 (* 1 = 0.350424 loss)
I0520 17:26:28.959149  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2600, loss = 0.247565
I0520 17:26:28.959192  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.247566 (* 1 = 0.247566 loss)
I0520 17:26:29.043840  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2600, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:26:44.058362  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2700, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:26:46.068781  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.896875
I0520 17:26:46.068824  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.332274 (* 1 = 0.332274 loss)
I0520 17:26:46.126523  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2700, loss = 0.377633
I0520 17:26:46.126566  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377634 (* 1 = 0.377634 loss)
I0520 17:26:46.211163  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2700, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:27:01.389209  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2800, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:27:03.399862  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.888125
I0520 17:27:03.399893  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.350417 (* 1 = 0.350417 loss)
I0520 17:27:03.456836  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2800, loss = 0.377626
I0520 17:27:03.456866  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377627 (* 1 = 0.377627 loss)
I0520 17:27:03.542301  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2800, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:27:18.608510  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 2900, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:27:20.618741  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.888125
I0520 17:27:20.618775  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.350423 (* 1 = 0.350423 loss)
I0520 17:27:20.675734  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 2900, loss = 0.377743
I0520 17:27:20.675763  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377744 (* 1 = 0.377744 loss)
I0520 17:27:20.761608  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 2900, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:27:36.487820  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3000, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:27:38.498106  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.888125
I0520 17:27:38.498141  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.350422 (* 1 = 0.350422 loss)
I0520 17:27:38.555095  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 3000, loss = 0.117625
I0520 17:27:38.555124  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.117626 (* 1 = 0.117626 loss)
I0520 17:27:38.651935  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 3000, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:27:54.956867  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3100, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:27:56.967296  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.8975
I0520 17:27:56.967337  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.330956 (* 1 = 0.330956 loss)
I0520 17:27:57.024297  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 3100, loss = 0.118173
I0520 17:27:57.024324  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.118174 (* 1 = 0.118174 loss)
I0520 17:27:57.118137  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 3100, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:28:13.332152  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3200, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:28:15.342835  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.896875
I0520 17:28:15.342877  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.332293 (* 1 = 0.332293 loss)
I0520 17:28:15.399948  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 3200, loss = 0.507063
I0520 17:28:15.399974  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.507064 (* 1 = 0.507064 loss)
I0520 17:28:15.496682  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 3200, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:28:31.541100  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3300, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:28:33.551388  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.898125
I0520 17:28:33.551429  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.32964 (* 1 = 0.32964 loss)
I0520 17:28:33.608397  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 3300, loss = 0.377692
I0520 17:28:33.608423  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377693 (* 1 = 0.377693 loss)
I0520 17:28:33.702908  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 3300, lr = 0.001
I0520 17:28:49.041621  8010 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 3400, Testing net (#0)
I0520 17:28:51.052881  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.89375
I0520 17:28:51.052911  8010 solver.cpp:404]     Test net output #1: loss = 0.338749 (* 1 = 0.338749 loss)
I0520 17:28:51.109899  8010 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 3400, loss = 0.377645
I0520 17:28:51.109926  8010 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.377646 (* 1 = 0.377646 loss)
I0520 17:28:51.194988  8010 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 3400, lr = 0.001
```

Followings are detail of the CNN.

Picture SNR are pretty low about 0.01.

Train set: 0-73167, 1-8888

Validation set: 0-24389, 1-2962

The CNN are designed for 2-class classification. I was inspired by deep residual network from Recently Microsoft Research Paper. 
Caffe code:

```
layer {
name: "Protein"
type: "Data"
top: "data"
top: "label"
include {
    phase: TRAIN
}
transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/data/mean.binaryproto"
}
data_param {
    source: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/data/train_db"
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
}
}

layer {
  name: "Protein"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_file: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/data/mean.binaryproto"
   # mean_file: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/data/test_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/data/val_db"
    #source: "/home/tg/Documents/caffe/my/protein/test_db"
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

layer{
    bottom: "data"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 256
        kernel_size: 5
        pad: 3
        stride: 2
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "bn_conv1"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "scale_conv1"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
    name: "relu_conv1"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "res1_branch2a"
    name: "res1_branch2a"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        kernel_size: 1
        pad: 0
        stride: 1
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2a"
    top: "res1_branch2a"
    name: "bn1_branch2a"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2a"
    top: "res1_branch2a"
    name: "scale1_branch2a"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2a"
    top: "res1_branch2a"
    name: "res1_branch2a_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2a"
    top: "res1_branch2b"
    name: "res1_branch2b"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 1
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2b"
    top: "res1_branch2b"
    name: "bn1_branch2b"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2b"
    top: "res1_branch2b"
    name: "scale1_branch2b"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2b"
    top: "res1_branch2b"
    name: "res1_branch2b_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2b"
    top: "res1_branch2c"
    name: "res1_branch2c"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 256
        kernel_size: 1
        pad: 0
        stride: 1
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2c"
    top: "res1_branch2c"
    name: "bn1_branch2c"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1_branch2c"
    top: "res1_branch2c"
    name: "scale1_branch2c"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "conv1"
    bottom: "res1_branch2c"
    top: "res1"
    name: "res1"
    type: "Eltwise"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1"
    top: "res1"
    name: "res1_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1"
    top: "res2_branch1"
    name: "res2_branch1"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 512
        kernel_size: 1
        pad: 0
        stride: 2
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch1"
    top: "res2_branch1"
    name: "bn2_branch1"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch1"
    top: "res2_branch1"
    name: "scale2_branch1"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res1"
    top: "res2_branch2a"
    name: "res2_branch2a"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 128
        kernel_size: 1
        pad: 0
        stride: 2
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2a"
    top: "res2_branch2a"
    name: "bn2_branch2a"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2a"
    top: "res2_branch2a"
    name: "scale2_branch2a"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2a"
    top: "res2_branch2a"
    name: "res2_branch2a_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2a"
    top: "res2_branch2b"
    name: "res2_branch2b"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 128
        kernel_size: 3
        pad: 1
        stride: 1
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2b"
    top: "res2_branch2b"
    name: "bn2_branch2b"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2b"
    top: "res2_branch2b"
    name: "scale2_branch2b"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2b"
    top: "res2_branch2b"
    name: "res2_branch2b_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2b"
    top: "res2_branch2c"
    name: "res2_branch2c"
    type: "Convolution"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 512
        kernel_size: 1
        pad: 0
        stride: 1
        bias_term: false
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2c"
    top: "res2_branch2c"
    name: "bn_branch2c"
    type: "BatchNorm"
    batch_norm_param {
        use_global_stats: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch2c"
    top: "res2_branch2c"
    name: "scale_branch2c"
    type: "Scale"
    scale_param {
        bias_term: true
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2_branch1"
    bottom: "res2_branch2c"
    top: "res2"
    name: "res2"
    type: "Eltwise"
}

layer {
    bottom: "res2"
    top: "res2"
    name: "res2_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer{
    bottom: "res2"
    top: "fc1"
    name: "fc1"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 128
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc1"
    top: "fc1_relu"
    name: "fc1_relu"
    type: "ReLU"
}

layer{
    bottom: "fc1_relu"
    top: "fc2"
    name: "fc2"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 2
    }
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}

layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

solver:

```
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 100
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
momentum: 0.9
stepsize: 2000
gamma: 0.3
weight_decay: 0.004
```

Comment: Is this accuracy too low comparing to your expectations? Maybe you simply cannot improve it due to inconsistency of your data?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a higher accuracy.  I have thought about the quality of data. But I can get the same accuracy on Lenet network with small(1e-4) learning rate in small number iteration. Maybe there are something wrong in my operation?

Comment: And what are exact percentages of each classes examples in your dataset?

Comment: I don't understand your description of the train/validation sets, are those the number of samples in each class?

Comment: Yeah! Train set: label 0 has 73167 pictures , label 1 has 8888 pictures.

Comment: Your dataset is extremely unbalanced, with 90% for one class, and 10% of the other class. What the CNN did is just predict the first class, where it will get 90% accuracy.

Comment: OH!!! that may gonna happen. So now I should check the precision and recall to ensure that situation whether happen. If the situation like you said was happened, should I reduce the number of label-0 ?